# The derivative, in the sense of distributions

Tags: derivatives, distribution-theory

Can you help please to solve this kind of tasks?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYfzP.jpg)
u(x) = (3x-1)

where p2(x) is given by 4 options

I tried to find and visited other topics and don't understand what I should do and what is delta(-1) and 1 in answers. I want to know how I can solve this kind of tasks.

I noticed that in which kind of samples I can find only derivate of the function to dx, in which case it will be "3" so I think it is connected with "3" so derivative of the function which equal to 3+p2(x) but the left part where sigmas I don't get it

Thank you very much I think I understood it, but to make sure I want to ask you, does the option **b) is correct?**

so δ(-1) = -4δ

And δ(1) = 2δ

So I got this -4δ(-1) + 2δ(1) + 3p2(x)

Did I found δ correctly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Indeed! What is $p_2(x)$?

Comment: Sorry I didnt get in this task what they want from me to find, they gave me function u(x) = (3x-1) in which (I dont know what is p2(x) is given by 4 options, which are in photos. Also in the options there are delta symbols + p2(x)

Comment: The [distribution $\delta_a$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#As_a_distribution) is defined by $\delta_a(f)=f(a).$ And they want you to compute the derivative of $u$ in the sense of distributions. But if you don't tell us what $p_2(x)$ is, we cannot help you more.

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you very much, I needed this formula, so now I can find the δa!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that $p_2(x)$ is defined as

$$p_2(x)=\begin{cases}
1&,-1<x<1\\\\0&,\text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

then for $u(x)=3x-1$, we have in distribution

$$\begin{align}
(u(x)p_2(x))&=u'(x)p_2(x)+u(x)p_2'(x)\\\\
&=3p_2(x)+(3x-1)p_2'(x)
\end{align}$$

where $p_2'$ is the distributional derivative of $p_2$.  Next, we shall analyze the distribution $p_2'$.

---

Let $\phi \in C_C^\infty$.  Using the definition of the distributional derivative, we assert that

$$\begin{align}
\langle p_2',\phi \rangle&=-\langle p_2,\phi' \rangle\\\\
&=-\int_{-1}^1 \phi'(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\phi(-1)-\phi(1) 
\end{align}$$

Hence, $p2'=\delta_{-1}-\delta_{1}$.

---

Putting it all together, we have in distribution

$$(up_2)'=(u(-1)\delta_{-1}-u(1)\delta_{1})u+3p_2$$

which can be written colloquially

$$\frac{d}{dx}(u(x)p_2(x))=-2\delta(x-1)-4\delta(x+1)+3p_2$$